# Function that takes a list input and returns a new list containing only the elements that are repeated

Tags: python, list

```
>>> list_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
>>> get_repeated(list_a)
['c']
```

What would be the most pythonic way to do function `get_repeated()`?

Comment: did you try anything youselft to get that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre] of ***your own*** attempt.

Comment: `list(set([i for i in list_a if list(list_a).count(i) > 1]))`

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```py
from collections import Counter

list_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
count = Counter(list_a)
output = [key for key, val in count.items() if val > 1]
```

```
print(output)
>>> ['c']
```